# Discrepancy in Replication

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to fix the problem of the difference in the number of rows in the destination and the source table. I check the replication monitor and it show that replication is working fine but then the is a difference of 300 tables between the source and destination.

Answer (score 1):

Are the tables in question included within your replication configuration, i.e. have the structures been explicitly selected for replication at the Publisher?

Newly created tables are not included automatically.

If not, you will need to update the Publication at the Publisher and can then update the replication topology accrodingly.

Make sense?

Cheers, John